# how to debug javascript files invoked from cypress test file

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, cypress

I'm running on Cypress version 12.14.0. I have my regular Cypress project structure. I have cypress.config.js and under e2e directory I have the test files such as test1.cy.js

What I'm unable to achieve is that I want to debug the JS code I invoked from my test file.

I have this call in my test1.cy.js test file

```
 cy.task('myTask', '', {
        options: { taskTimeout: 3600000 }
      }).then(()=>{
        cy.debug()
      })
```

then I have this definiton in my cypress.config.js

```
...
const fileUtils = require('./Utils/FileUtils.js')
...
    setupNodeEvents: async function (on, config) {
      on('task', {
        myTask() {
          fileUtils.checkFiles()
          return true
        }
      })
    }
```

and in my FileUtils.js file:

```
...

async function checkFiles(){

/*
my code i want to debug line by line
*/

}

module.exports = {
  checkFiles:checkFiles
}
```

then I run cypress using command

`npx cypress open`

then I select chrome and open Dev Tools by pressing F12. then the debugger kicks in for the line `cy.debug()` in my cy.js file. However, from this point forward, I find FileUtils.js in the "Sources" tab of DevTools and put a breakpoint in the line I want, but it never goes into the breakpoint but I verify that the code where I put the breakpoint is actually executed successfully.

So. How can I debug a function defined in a JS file that is invoked from within a cypress cy.js test file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypress debug can't be used inside a task as far as I know.

The test code is what `cy.debug()` is designed for and the test code runs in the the browser.

Tasks run in the NodeJs part of Cypress runner. You already have a separate module for `checkFiles()` so you should be able to run debug using [Node.js debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging), running separately from the Cypress tests.

> The Visual Studio Code editor has built-in debugging support for the Node.js runtime and can debug JavaScript, TypeScript, and many other languages that are transpiled into JavaScript.
>
> **Auto Attach**
>
> If the Auto Attach feature is enabled, the Node debugger automatically attaches to certain Node.js processes that have been launched from VS Code's Integrated Terminal.

Comment: i ended up doing what you described. thanks!